# Http GET of source containing non-UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, get

I solved an issue I had with retrieving and displaying non-UTF-8 characters but I don't understand *why* my solution works.

The following code:

```
final HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
final HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(urlString);
client.executeMethod(method);
final String responseBodyAsString = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
System.out.println(responseBodyAsString);
```

was messing up some characters on the display, such as YÃ¡Ã±ez

I changed:

```
final String responseBodyAsString = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

to

```
final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(method.getResponseBody());
final String responseBodyAsString = new String(inputBuffer.array());
```

and the same string as before is represented correctly as Yáñez

Why is that?

Comment: The correct way to ask the server to send UTF-8 data is to use a `Accept-Charset: utf-8` request header, not a `Content-Type` request header.

Comment: And on top of that, the correct way is NOT to change the characters. Many people thing "oh, it is just an n with a squiggle" but in fact it is a different letter. What would you think if some software would change Q to O "well, it is just O with a squiggle"

Comment: @RemyLebeau See my update, which fixed the issue.  I didn't have to specify either the charset or the content type.  Is that because the httpclient has some mechanism for knowing what character to use?

Comment: @MihaiNita Point taken: there are good reasons for additional characters and removing them isn't ideal.  I can't comment for Spanish but in French if we are stuck to UTF-8, changing letters like ç, é to c and e is a mistake but still the best approach available.  So if someone didn't have a Q, then yes, a O would be reasonable to answer your question.  That being said, in the current example, I was able to get around my problem and display the characters properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getResponseBodyAsString()` uses the HTTP response's `Content-Type` header to know what the response body's charset is so the data can be converted to a `String` as needed.  `getResponseBody()` simply returns the body's raw bytes as-is, which you are then converting to a `String` using the platform's default charset.  Since you are able to get the desired `String` output by converting the raw bytes manually, that suggests to me that the HTTP server is not specifying a charset in the response's `Content-Type` header at all, or is specifying the wrong charset.

`YÃ¡Ã±ez` is the UTF-8 encoded version of `Yáñez`, so it is odd that the `String(bytes[])` constructor would be able to decode it correctly, unless the platform's default charset is actually UTF-8.  It does make sense for `getResponseBodyAsString()` to return `YÃ¡Ã±ez` if the response charset used is `ISO-8859-1`, which is the default charset for `text/...` media types sent over HTTP when no charset is explicitly specified, per RFC 2616 Section 3.7.1.

I would suggest looking for a bug in the server script that is sending the data (or reporting a bug report to the server admin), before suspecting a bug with `getResponseBodyAsString()`.  You can use a packet sniffer like Wireshark, or a debugging proxy like Fiddler, to confirm the missing/invalid charset in the response `Content-Type` header.

Comment: Great explanation, thanks.  I did wget -d and saw what you were suspecting: no charset specified in the response: "Accept-Ranges: bytes... Content-Type: text/xml".  I do not understand your comment about it being odd that String(bytes[]) decodes correctly unless the platform is UTF-8. Wouldn't it be the contrary? I.e. only if the platform supports a set able to display Yáñez would it work?  I ran my code with Eclipse on a mac FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Try the next:

```
private static final String UNICODE = "ÀàÈèÌìÒòÙùÁáÉéÍíÓóÚúÝýÂâÊêÎîÔôÛûŶŷÃãÕõÑñÄäËëÏïÖöÜüŸÿÅåÇçŐőŰű";
private static final String PLAIN_ASCII = "AaEeIiOoUuAaEeIiOoUuYyAaEeIiOoUuYyAaOoNnAaEeIiOoUuYyAaCcOoUu";

public static String convertNonAscii(String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        int pos = UNICODE.indexOf(c);
        if (pos > -1)
            sb.append(PLAIN_ASCII.charAt(pos));
        else {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^\\x00-\\x7E]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    System.out.println(p.matcher(UNICODE).find());
    System.out.println(p.matcher(PLAIN_ASCII).find());
    System.out.println(convertNonAscii("ú or ñ"));
}
```

Output:

```
true
false
u or n
```